# Fast Fourier Transform adjust scaling

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm trying to show trends of my data by doing a FFT. The data I want to perform a FFT on looks like this:

[image: Raw data]

Within every year we see a clear trend almost like a sin wave and I thought this should be visible after a FFT transformation but I got this:

[image: FFT]

On the x-axis is hours and on the y-axis the detrended data also in W/m^2. Originally every data point was taken every 16 day within the same year. However, this is not necessarily the case between transitions of two years.

For the FFT I used this code and the detrended data `data_plot_multi_year1["y"]-mean(data_plot_multi_year1["y"]` can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/Tf2gSEaK):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hann = np.hanning(len(data_plot_multi_year1["y"]))

Y = np.fft.fft(hann*(data_plot_multi_year1["y"]-mean(data_plot_multi_year1["y"])))
N = len(Y)/2+1
fa = 1.0 / (16.0*24*60.0* 60.0)  # every 16th day
print('fa=%.7fHz (Frequency)' % fa)

X = np.linspace(0, fa/2, N, endpoint=True)
Xp = 1.0/X                 # in seconds
Xph = Xp /(60.0*60.0*24)   # in days

plt.figure()
plt.plot(Xph, 2.0 * np.abs(Y[:N]) / N)
plt.show()
```

Since this is my first time doing something like this, does it need to look like this or how can I make the trends more visible?

The original data is here: [y values](https://pastebin.com/87tw6jkM) and [x values](https://pastebin.com/J68kk8A8).

Comment: Don’t plot your x-axis in Hz, use cycles/year, then see if you find a peak at 1. Hz is kind of meaningless when dealing with a yearly cycle.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, so you mean edit `Xph = Xp /(60.0*60.0*24*365)   # in years` like that?

Comment: I tried plotting the data from your pastebin, it doesn't at all look like the data you show in your first graph. The data in your graph I expect to have a much strong peak at 1 cycle/year than at other frequencies. The plots in the answer below don't make sense when looking at your graph, but they do match the data in your pastebin. Please verify you're using the right data!!!

Comment: @CrisLuengo: If you run the code with the pastebin data you get the fft plot. If you want to reproduce the first plot, **scatter** plot data_plot_multi_year1["y"] vs. data_plot_multi_year1["x"] from here: [https://pastebin.com/87tw6jkM ] (for y) and [ https://pastebin.com/J68kk8A8 ] (for x)

Comment: Ah, that is very different data!

Comment: well, data_plot_multi_year1["y"] is the same in both cases. However, the data is detrended for the FFT with: plot data_plot_multi_year1["y"]-np.mean(data_plot_multi_year1["y"])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the original data, I see a very different plot than if I look at the detrended data that you (and the other answers) have used to compute the FFT from.

So, starting with this original data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplt as pp

# Data
y = np.array([4.9163581574416115, 4.5232489635722359, 5.1418668265986014, 4.7243929349211378, 5.0922668745097237, 3.2505877068809528, 5.266713471351407, 3.2593612955944398, 6.0329599566748149, 5.501028641922999, 3.6033946768899154, 4.0640736190761837, 3.9015401707437629, 4.5497509491042667, 3.7227800407604765, 3.3294036636861795, 3.2400339075816058, 3.4354831362560447, 5.0721090065474757, 4.2898468699869312, 3.9352309911472898, 4.6544147503812772, 3.5076460922078962, 4.8823458504641311, 3.006733596435486, 3.3404353221374912, 4.2604198197171943, 3.5110363901532828, 4.7495904044204913, 4.4755614380567836, 2.8255977501087353, 4.0147937265525631, 4.6982506962329369, 4.1073988606130554, 4.3779635559151062, 3.8455643143910585, 2.8446707334831589, 3.8864340895006602, 5.407473632935444, 3.7776659978957676, 3.7474804428857103, 4.4231421808719968, 4.1145572839087201, 3.4407172122286807, 5.7068484749384503, 3.3175924030243089, 2.8563413179332078, 3.520760038353695, 3.9712227784619754, 5.0318859983482076, 3.7642574784532088, 3.4828932021013372, 3.2259745458147786, 5.032377633970162, 5.2464640619126435, 4.9482379500988491, 3.798306221105471, 3.3672821755011646, 4.8054046257516898, 4.5758461857175972, 4.4079132488332275, 3.5862463276840586, 5.0281771086563696, 3.9038881511201029, 3.5464781504503957, 3.752348181547787, 3.1520445958602115, 4.370394739799015, 3.896389496115487, 4.118225887215103, 4.802537302837913, 4.1800322086907791, 3.9270327778098264, 2.9892139644432794, 3.5412442495098522, 4.9353516122953636, 3.6311330623837823, 3.4788493170853205, 3.4571475745293054, 5.3964493189396956, 4.0166801210413112, 3.184902965087919, 4.3231987474246907, 3.821044625315142, 3.2501749085457448, 4.1218393070599149, 3.4907498564324784, 3.7048147909485549, 4.4067985127175193, 3.2628048471339661, 3.4299356612804384, 3.054687769820104, 3.4394826446333515, 3.8926147692854536, 3.5274891297329392, 5.1600491179626147, 5.1267218406912436, 4.9196604682508616, 3.288844643645831, 5.0123334575721739, 5.8837792219610296, 3.6525485317948769, 5.2655629050160382, 4.5940509381861077, 3.5326474318629821, 4.7549446018611174, 5.5400627941766389, 4.2340183526794908, 3.833235556736899, 4.1055923866919404, 3.9041368756551273, 2.8355474432294439, 5.0365898742249708, 5.558027054794378, 3.0385703101397779, 4.1301188661365806, 3.4824265559683489, 3.9319218096961523, 3.0332372505317466, 4.0506899500473681, 5.298987852183183, 3.2070084334136282, 3.4802868005912773, 3.2223945502453342, 3.6057387919024859, 4.1135183367430654, 5.4774825204501179, 3.7504701089542696, 3.3997275593227916, 4.0280467030451277, 5.1921516666697185, 4.1662957219173871, 4.9276361137412961, 4.3055659900345269, 4.2160192742975298, 4.5582352743558525, 3.5779282232857184, 3.3303571863388153, 4.7062814020334001, 3.763690626719586, 4.020276538555315, 3.2952422897541718, 4.3944836078620826, 5.0651527836251846, 3.2736433168588834, 4.0164274892409875, 4.6926928415631961, 3.5439697283257536, 4.8170195490454715, 5.1717553137007295, 4.47489761280195, 4.2721415529277245, 3.7722293780212186, 4.6163723178866256, 3.4852465925030596, 3.5081857100611429, 4.9526591274218141, 2.7418823869877671, 5.2309064498443112, 2.9584799885836368, 5.9208165893988971, 3.7266204734555268, 3.9696836775155155, 3.0817605147405351, 5.3501874894485368, 4.823298910487158, 4.094371587882315, 3.666534185013655, 4.3613972464934943, 3.5253937700241282, 3.5114759216562974, 3.7387872601144321, 3.2428544820295313, 4.3174760573045647, 3.8153701553661081, 5.3510324878858881, 5.887473202470229, 5.2483141940171967, 3.6730647722321899, 3.2527108096051762, 5.087119161099805, 5.4376786692500971, 5.1985667958007626, 4.0776721320121245, 4.0746559030897966, 5.3838863415603209, 2.9772622863398106, 4.4371692352610923, 4.824375079864156, 5.1574523180746281, 3.6417281403335027, 3.7353723232513896, 4.8786928981111108, 3.1549797688883685, 4.9273350311811477, 4.8909872856262631, 5.0733312023802286, 4.7195548768733193, 3.2117711403989326, 4.0607353048756289, 3.2068686273897913, 3.8104210279601221, 4.0764549403056849, 5.1905644211359325, 4.9059727970323124, 4.3312408753376159, 4.495834529789291, 3.7017758002769088, 3.8928592560408886, 3.3590820111611572, 5.6800192429325946, 5.2801982921123018, 3.4971867534798688, 4.1434397763487363, 5.0320214435810486, 3.2572048463905596, 3.5708589225079157, 5.5420277180979705, 4.816537191178262, 4.7123032533220774, 4.6276901989665546, 3.3033314780041207, 3.7031834923679217, 4.9531169434719784, 3.9520303484745076, 4.7069324020275154, 3.3485205880519819, 3.578929442922882, 5.0416858356367751, 3.2471486950110151, 4.8036517687546469, 2.9564023409041931, 4.370824090704172, 3.3111933909292781, 5.4693269793385397, 5.9471091984264612, 5.5997609124508001, 3.253791264246908, 5.5589687791680173, 4.0347612835986313, 5.0860759232647048, 3.8236359577497381, 4.2502050750154163, 5.3804473886648889, 3.0777806788604702, 4.3119059095678196, 3.6076909731506221, 3.6675311219295414, 4.5761803934468732, 4.1294871300142644, 3.6827073669759471, 3.9918347122796098, 3.4194166080890587, 5.3442479778374041, 3.325200562869143, 5.4364117543671719, 2.7691861112204053, 3.2431028421965107, 5.7997059152735284, 5.1396423172415746, 3.8341163596077106, 4.6158592382839672, 5.2991510313934427, 4.2613846468512486, 3.3747692135915655, 3.7002229064232939, 3.1618285314537342, 5.3066215213431933, 3.4764287458899688, 4.2664404462781276, 3.7020536806298709, 4.4920788644955021, 4.7765300011524729, 3.6234351180642332, 4.2676647387441031, 3.1419131638878253, 5.0149070978243522, 3.6335404191164362, 5.6667351882464283, 3.4029057890404824, 4.1230483413169239, 4.8245272024467116, 3.65830252796454, 4.4813334423826712, 3.6740443622552865, 4.1977102616532935, 4.1320785201142503, 3.1085193591271505, 5.0012055352868723, 4.0428697712217607, 5.201396550122233, 5.5110799401116326, 3.2437611839952023, 4.8397817377344712, 5.4850675142216154, 3.627247179469125, 4.0577205671254726, 2.5798969377153802, 4.6359100698702171, 4.7640011574006191, 5.8635971341249009, 3.6510638760009013, 3.2845760628978011, 5.1435067636186025, 3.8973081092150159, 3.1445177808730125, 3.5112954060023718, 5.5052935046977147, 4.0618208001814811, 5.2828398404225272, 4.8693030005934981, 3.413421242301824, 5.7045184220496115, 5.3221412413004741, 4.3631763041559992, 4.188513180452488, 3.9197228949008855, 4.2780523472142535, 3.695429486781181, 4.8294238192705237, 5.264103644882745, 5.0998049360010391, 5.5094161509890887, 4.3214874721201451, 3.6102609731613162, 5.2723061570113243, 3.8298642965515364, 4.8098072099418445, 3.632970055942816, 3.5542517670129983, 4.9124440128270983, 5.0786806222541223, 5.0248576192789542, 5.0029379966378063, 3.1383857221712161, 5.4119593837374813, 5.2071519069366392, 4.81942138782507, 5.4131759970726518, 4.9823428242283274, 4.0704364655939997, 3.6092965241074735, 4.7229918731679614, 4.7586642729235562, 3.9002260395078925])
x = np.array([2817, 1960, 3500, 1357, 183, 1482, 1642, 372, 2008, 1626, 2641, 5228, 2865, 4277, 1437, 3612, 359, 752, 5276, 1578, 1754, 1341, 2212, 1261, 4402, 2593, 3054, 4021, 5008, 3420, 676, 3324, 2340, 2136, 4149, 3278, 71, 1024, 4944, 3752, 1181, 628, 2657, 3736, 4594, 3976, 4738, 5132, 5452, 532, 3372, 1546, 2913, 5260, 2753, 2769, 311, 1072, 5340, 3198, 5372, 2625, 1690, 4482, 2990, 4309, 4373, 848, 3356, 295, 1706, 2308, 39, 2244, 4450, 1213, 1149, 4085, 2926, 2372, 3388, 708, 5056, 4816, 5180, 103, 4690, 4706, 2468, 4466, 452, 3720, 1880, 2184, 4752, 2705, 215, 1610, 4008, 3864, 1658, 468, 199, 5388, 3596, 516, 3150, 1738, 5212, 5404, 2881, 1848, 2420, 5308, 4418, 4514, 768, 4053, 2577, 5104, 4960, 3308, 4101, 816, 4784, 1117, 2356, 3656, 4117, 3262, 3118, 644, 1245, 5072, 3784, 2673, 5196, 3960, 3532, 5436, 5040, 4722, 4642, 960, 420, 484, 4880, 5148, 2088, 4229, 1594, 1944, 327, 3912, 784, 1088, 247, 388, 1992, 1466, 3086, 1802, 2484, 4325, 3468, 3166, 1421, 3628, 2452, 2958, 2532, 4386, 23, 1197, 5088, 4546, 2388, 596, 4832, 4357, 1293, 1309, 4992, 4848, 119, 3848, 55, 1008, 3816, 612, 2168, 4768, 5324, 2276, 1976, 2801, 4610, 3516, 3688, 1040, 3992, 4674, 3944, 2056, 4261, 5244, 1722, 4341, 3580, 736, 896, 2785, 3644, 279, 5292, 4037, 1770, 4197, 3038, 976, 3214, 2609, 2500, 3436, 1405, 1229, 1133, 2260, 151, 1896, 3800, 4069, 4133, 4434, 564, 4578, 3102, 2196, 912, 3564, 4896, 5420, 4658, 2721, 87, 2104, 5116, 1928, 2833, 2120, 1056, 3928, 1832, 231, 1498, 2024, 404, 1818, 1674, 3070, 3340, 864, 3484, 4293, 2974, 2548, 343, 2404, 1453, 1389, 1562, 5356, 4165, 2228, 1373, 2561, 4530, 2942, 1277, 692, 1514, 5024, 2516, 4864, 1912, 4800, 2152, 3672, 992, 3246, 3832, 4928, 1165, 2324, 2040, 1864, 3768, 3704, 3880, 2689, 944, 1530, 5164, 2072, 5468, 436, 2897, 4245, 1101, 3134, 3896, 800, 2737, 167, 263, 3404, 3022, 4498, 1786, 1325, 3452, 3182, 880, 2849, 3292, 4976, 832, 2436, 7, 2292, 4562, 548, 4181, 580, 724, 928, 4213, 4626, 4912, 3548, 660, 3230, 135, 500, 3006])
```

We first notice that the x-values are not sorted. Let's sort the data:

```
# Sort data on x values
index = np.argsort(x)
y = y[index]
x = x[index]
```

Next, we notice that the x locations are not evenly spaced. The FFT expects even-spaced data. Let's resample the data to make it evenly spaced:

```
# Interpolate data so it is regularly sampled
n = len(x)
newx = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], n)
y = np.interp(newx, x, y)
x = newx
```

Now we can confidently compute the FFT and plot, just like in the question:

```
# Compute FFT and plot
Y = np.fft.fft(y - np.mean(y))
fa = 365.0 / (x[1] - x[0]) # samples/year
N = n//2+1
X = np.linspace(0, fa/2, N)

pp.figure()
pp.plot(X, abs(Y[:N])) # I'm ignoring all that scaling here, it's irrelevant...
pp.show()
```

[image: Graph of frequency domain]

We now clearly see a peak at 1 cycle/year, as expected!

Comment: I must say this looks more reasonable...If you use my code and define the y you took as `data_plot_multi_year1["y"]` wouldn't you get the same (second) plot as mine shown in the question? Why is there a difference? Could it be due to the unevenly spaced data? Moreover, what's the unit on the y-axis. It seems to be extremely large.

Comment: @Shaun: I’m pretty sure the main problem was the sorting. If your samples come in a random order, Fourier analysis is meaningless. The interpolation to make the samples evenly spaced is less important, because they were close to evenly spaced. Still, don’t skip that step if you’re serious. You should always start with plotting your data: `plot(data_plot_multi_year1["y"])` shows data without any periodicity. After sorting, you can see the beautiful yearly trend. The y-axis unit is meaningless, as the comment in my code indicates. I just wanted to show the shape of the curve.

Comment: @Shaun: Also, subtracting the mean is not detrending. You need to fit a trend and subtract that, if you want to detrend. The mean only affects the first bin of the FFT. Subtracting the mean is identical to setting that bin to 0.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much I learned a lot right now. In your code where you define `fa = 356.0 / (x[1] - x[0]) # samples/year`, where does 356.0 come from? Do you mean 365.0 as in number of days in 1 year?

Comment: @Shaun: Ha! Yes, a typo. 365 days/year. This is not exact, maybe 365.25 would be better (think leap years), but I don’t think such a small difference matters. As you can see on the graph, you can be 11 days off (typo) and still get a good result. :)

Comment: Ok, I'm getting the same plot now! But I need to know what the units of the y-axis  is. Does FFT change the units of the initial data? In my code, due to the y-values which made sense, I thought it would be the same units (W/m^2 in my case)

Comment: @Shaun: In your own code you divided by `N` and multiplied by 2. I’ve seen similar normalizations before. Dividing by `N` certainly makes sense. The zero frequency value of the FFT is the sum of all input samples. So dividing by `N` puts that at the mean input level. So yes, the units in the FD domain are the same as in the spatial domain.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and I learned so much within the last hour! You sir deserve an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

To start off, you should not plot the FFT vs time `Xp` or `Xph` in the code given. The fft represents frequencies, and should be plotted against 1/time. This is why your spectrum does not look evenly sampled.

Here is how to do it, based on the data link you gave, stored in `data`.

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq, fftshift

Y = fftshift(fft(data, n=2**12))
fa = 1/16   # in days
f = fftshift(fftfreq(len(Y), 1/fa))

plt.plot(f, abs(Y)/len(data))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Since the raw data is very noisy, so is the FFT, and it is hard to discern the dominant frequency. There are some ways to mitigate this, for example compute the Welch spectrum, which is like a moving average of the data in frequency domain.

```
from scipy.signal import welch
fw, Pxx = welch(data, fa, nperseg=128, nfft=2**12, scaling='spectrum')    
plt.plot(fw, Pxx)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is a little less noisier, and it shows that there is a a peak around 0.025 day^-1, or every 40 days. You probably need a little higher sampling rate (e.g. every day rather than every 16 days to be more confident about this, but my understanding may be wrong...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! Could you explain what the n is for here: `Y = fftshift(fft(data, n=2**12))`According to the docs it's: Length of the transformed axis. Why does it need to be so large? Moreover, what about the units in the welch spectrum? Is it also (W/m^2)^2 like it would be for a psd or the same units as the initial data?

Comment: `n` is the number of fft points to use. If n > len(data), then data is just zero padded before computing the fft. This simply makes the plot resolution (spacing between points in fft) better. For Welch, according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) the units is as you expected for `scaling='spectrum'`.

Comment: Cool thank you very much. One more thing though: You said I shouldn't plot my data vs. my Xph time but 0.020Hz or 1/days is very hard to read so I thought I could convert it into something more readable...Isn't that possible? Maybe months or so

Answer (score 0):

The `fft` gives how much each sine wave of different frequencies contributes to your signal.

If you look to the graph, there are peaks on it. 
That means that the sine waves with those frequencies contribute more to your signal.

So your year trend is represented by one of these peaks. However there are also other strong components since your data is not a pure sine wave

Comment: I see! When I change `Xph = Xp /(60.0*60.0*24*365) # in years` and zoom in there's a (small) peak at 1 year. Is there a better way to plot it? use a different plotting styl or something which is more common for those kind of plots?

Comment: Great work analyzing it! Sometimes I like to plot only the stem plot because it is easier to check each individual frequency